# representation of riemann stieltjes integral as riemann integral

Tags: riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be an absolutely continuous function. It is known that the absolutely continuous function $g$ is diffentiable a.e. and there holds $$g(y)-g(x)=\int_x^y g'\;\mbox{d}t$$ for every $x,y\in[a,b]$. Can we somehow use these facts to prove that for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral there holds $$\int_a^b f\;\mbox{d}g=\int_a^b fg'\;\mbox{d}x?$$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $$f(x^{\ast}_i)\cdot \bigl(g(x_{i+1} - g(x_i)\bigr) = f(x_i^{\ast})\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} g'(t)\,dt$$

Comment: of course, we should start with this but what could be the next step ?

Comment: Considering $$\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} \bigl(f(t) - f(x_i^{\ast})\bigr) g'(t)\,dt.$$

Comment: and now we use the continuity of $f$, ok thank you, I get it